# Triple Integral $F = \iiint_SGm\delta(x,y,z)f(x,y,z) \space dx \space dy \space dz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $S$ be a basic solid and let $(a,b,c)$ be a point not in $S$. If $S$ has continuously varying mass density of $\delta = \delta(x,y,z)$ then $S$ attracts a point mass $m$ located at $a,b,c$ with a gravitational force $$F = \iiint_SGm\delta(x,y,z)f(x,y,z) \space dx \space dy \space  dz$$ where $$f(x,y,z) = \dfrac{(x-a)\textbf{i}+(y-b)\textbf{j}+(z-c)\textbf{k}}{[(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2]^{3/2}}$$ is the force experienced by a particle in an inverse square field Let $S$ be a solid right circular cylinder of constant density, with base radius $R$, height $h$ and mass $M$. A point mass $m$ is placed on the axis of $S$ at a distance $\alpha$ from the nearest base of the cylinder. Find the gravitational force exerted by the cylinder on the point mass.

**Hint:** In developing the integral $F$ you might like to consider only the non-zero components due to the gravitational symmetry of the problem.

> How would you even go about starting this question? How would you setup the range for a triple integral like this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would try to first draw a picture. It seems that cylindrical coordinates is the way to go.

Comment: It is asking to compute $\displaystyle F(a) = G M\iiint_{X_1^2+X_2^2 = R^2, X_3 \in [0,h]}  \frac{X-a}{|X-a|^3} d^3 X$

Comment: @reuns Is it possible to build on that a little bit? Not making any ground on this. Thanks

Comment: @reuns is $a$ a vector in this case, or the actual point $a$ (in your comment)

Comment: $X-a$ is the vector from $a $ to $X$, $|X-a|$ is its norm and $GM \frac{X-a}{|X-a|^3}$ is the force applied at $X$ by a point mass $M$ at $a$. And I meant $X_1^2+X_2^2 \le R^2$